# wiring a arduino led project

Tags: wires

I am moving a project from breadboard and jumper cables.
It light a bunch of LEDs with different sets running of many almost every pin.
I need a few meters of cables.
I will a resistor on each led.
I have no idea what kinda cable/wire to use and googling cable gets me nowhere.
What kinda wire do people use?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but would [ribbon cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_cable) fit the bill?

Comment: Otherwise, describe what sort of cable you're looking for (presumably you have some sort of idea) and someone may know what it's called.

Answer (score 2):

When choosing wire for your project the main consideration is the amount of current. Second would be the distance.

For LEDs the current is generally low (milliamps) so something like a 20 or 22 gauge wire would be fine. You should be able to get it at a local hobby electronics shop or [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_13?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=22+guage+wire+electronic&sprefix=22+guage+wire%2Caps%2C202&crid=1ANPJ8T93086Y) of course.

FYI, Wire gauge numbering is such that the lower the number the thicker wire. Thus 20 is thicker than 22.

You may find this AWG (American Wire Gauge) table helpful: http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

Comment: With careful choice of wire thickness and length paying close attention to the resistance-per-meter it may be possible to do away with the LED resistors entirely and use the resistance of the wire instead.